# $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push not working inside of on(change) jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, datatable

I am having trouble to generate a date filter (selection box in HTML) that shows selected date option from the table(Today, Yesterday, Last 7 Days, Last 30 Days, Last 60 Days, and Last 90 Days).

Somehow the code in $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push does not fire up. Please help me out!

[Search Filter Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyk6g.png)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectByDate').on('change', function () {
        var minDate = new Date();
        if (document.getElementById("selectByDate").value == "Today") {
            $("#maxInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate);
            $("#minInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate);
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                    var date1 = data[0].split(" ");
                    var date2 = date1[0].split("-");
                    var min = $('#minInput').datepicker("getDate");
                    var max = $('#maxInput').datepicker("getDate");
                    var startDate = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);
                    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 1);
                    if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
                    else if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true; }
                    else if (max == null && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    else if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    else { return false; }
                });
            $("#minInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
            $("#maxInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });

            $('#minInput, #maxInput').change(function () {
                table.draw();
            });

        } else if (document.getElementById("selectByDate").value == "Yesterday") {
            $("#maxInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - 1));
            $("#minInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate);
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                    var date1 = data[0].split(" ");
                    var date2 = date1[0].split("-");
                    var min = $('#minInput').datepicker("getDate");
                    var max = $('#maxInput').datepicker("getDate");
                    var startDate = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);
                    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 1);
                    if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
                    else if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true; }
                    else if (max == null && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    else if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    else { return false; }
                });
            $("#minInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
            $("#maxInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });

            $('#minInput, #maxInput').change(function () {
                table.draw();
            });

        } else if (document.getElementById("selectByDate").value == "Last 7 Days") {
            $("#maxInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - 7));
            $("#minInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate);
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                    var date1 = data[0].split(" ");
                    var date2 = date1[0].split("-");
                    var min = $('#minInput').datepicker("getDate");
                    var max = $('#maxInput').datepicker("getDate");
                    var startDate = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);
                    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 1);
                    if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
                    else if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true; }
                    else if (max == null && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    else if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    else { return false; }
                });
            $("#minInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
            $("#maxInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });

            $('#minInput, #maxInput').change(function () {
                table.draw();
            });

        } else if (document.getElementById("selectByDate").value == "Last 30 Days") {
            $("#maxInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - 30));
            $("#minInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate);
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                    var date1 = data[0].split(" ");
                    var date2 = date1[0].split("-");
                    var min = $('#minInput').datepicker("getDate");
                    var max = $('#maxInput').datepicker("getDate");
                    var startDate = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);
                    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 1);
                    if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
                    else if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true; }
                    else if (max == null && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    else if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    else { return false; }
                });
            $("#minInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
            $("#maxInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });

            $('#minInput, #maxInput').change(function () {
                table.draw();
            });

        } else if (document.getElementById("selectByDate").value == "Last 60 Days") {
            $("#maxInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - 60));
            $("#minInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate);
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                    var date1 = data[0].split(" ");
                    var date2 = date1[0].split("-");
                    var min = $('#minInput').datepicker("getDate");
                    var max = $('#maxInput').datepicker("getDate");
                    var startDate = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);
                    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 1);
                    if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
                    else if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true; }
                    else if (max == null && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    else if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    else { return false; }
                });
            $("#minInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
            $("#maxInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });

            $('#minInput, #maxInput').change(function () {
                table.draw();
            });

        } else if (document.getElementById("selectByDate").value == "Last 90 Days") {
            $("#maxInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - 90));
            $("#minInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate);
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                    var date1 = data[0].split(" ");
                    var date2 = date1[0].split("-");
                    var min = $('#minInput').datepicker("getDate");
                    var max = $('#maxInput').datepicker("getDate");
                    var startDate = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);
                    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 1);
                    if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
                    else if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true; }
                    else if (max == null && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    else if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                    else { return false; }
                });
            $("#minInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
            $("#maxInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });

            $('#minInput, #maxInput').change(function () {
                table.draw();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code has lot of duplicate data which can be avoided.

`$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push` need to be defined only once.

Here is shorter version from 150 lines to just 50.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var date1 = data[0].split(" ");
            var date2 = date1[0].split("-");
            var min = $('#minInput').datepicker("getDate");
            var max = $('#maxInput').datepicker("getDate");
            var startDate = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);
            startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 1);
            if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
            else if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true; }
            else if (max == null && startDate >= min) { return true; }
            else if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
            else { return false; }
        });


    $('#selectByDate').on('change', function () {
        var minDate = new Date();
        $("#minInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate);
        if (document.getElementById("selectByDate").value == "Today") {
            $("#maxInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate);
        } else if (document.getElementById("selectByDate").value == "Yesterday") {
            $("#maxInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - 1));
        } else if (document.getElementById("selectByDate").value == "Last 7 Days") {
            $("#maxInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - 7));
        } else if (document.getElementById("selectByDate").value == "Last 30 Days") {
            $("#maxInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - 30));
        } else if (document.getElementById("selectByDate").value == "Last 60 Days") {
            $("#maxInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - 60));
        } else if (document.getElementById("selectByDate").value == "Last 90 Days") {
            $("#maxInput").datepicker("setDate", minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - 90));
        }


    });

    $('#minInput, #maxInput').change(function () {
        table.draw();
    });

    $("#minInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });

    $("#maxInput").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });



});
```

Try this code if still you have issue refer [this link with demo](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)

Comment: Hi TwoCents, I have tried the code above before I post the question, but it was not drawing the table. "$('#selectByDate').on('change', function () " did change the value of mixInput and minInput, but it did not redraw the table.

Comment: I don't know how you have defined the table in table.draw();  It has to be a Datatable Object.  2.  check your logic for search.push function   3. check if Datatable version you are using supports search.push extension.